# How to block/redirect global keyboard events in cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, events, keyboard, global

I have setup global keyboard trap using following code:

```
    self.machPortRef =  CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap,
                                         kCGTailAppendEventTap,
                                         kCGEventTapOptionDefault,
                                         CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp),
                                         (CGEventTapCallBack)eventTapFunction,
                                         self);
```

How can i block/redirect keydown events of front most active window in my cocoa app. I tried to return NULL in eventTapFunction, but it didn't block the event.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `NSApplication`, and override `-sendEvent:`

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution.